# KDE: Disable touchpad while typing

Tags: touchpad, kde

How can I disable the touchpad while typing on KDE?

Is there such a setting like in gnome?

Answer (score 8):

Application menu -> Utilities -> touchpad management. There, you can ask the system to disable the touchpad when a usb mouse is connected and/or when you are typing.

Comment: Thanks - I do not find this menu entry. Do you know which command line is assigned to this menu entry?

Comment: In Kubuntu 12.10 press ALT+F2 and launch `synaptiks`

Comment: Tried this from a shell but got:
synaptiks: command not found

So I tried installing and got:
sudo apt-get install synaptiks
E: Unable to locate package synaptiks

Answer (score 5):

#### KDE 4 or 5

KDE 4: `sudo apt install kde-touchpad`

`kcmshell5 kcm_touchpad` or `kcmshell4 kcm_touchpad`

And you'll even have an option to disable touch and scroll only, leaving you the ability to move the cursor.

Comment: kde-touchpad installed, but not the other packages: 
E: Unable to locate package kcmshell4
E: Unable to locate package kcm_touchpad

Comment: It's two separate commands, the second one just launches settings interface.

Comment: The command literally opened the same settings page as I already had found in the settings app and there is no option to disable touchpad while typing. It's enabled though and I want to find a way to disable it.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try touchpad-indicator? You can install it using these commands while in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator
```